# Tastypie URLs not configured properly

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I get the following error when I try to access http://localhost:8000/api/goal/?format=json:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/goal/
The included urlconf <property object at 0x262bb50> doesn't have any patterns in it
```

Here is what I have added to my urls.py:

```
goal_resource = GoalResource

...

    url(r'^api/', include(goal_resource.urls)),
```

Here is my api.py:

```
class GoalResource(ModelResource):
  class Meta:
    queryset = Goal.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'goal'
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call GoalResource, not just bind it's memory address to variable. So change

```
goal_resource = GoalResource
```

to

```
goal_resource = GoalResource()
```